# Why can I only edit a comment 5 minutes after it was posted?

Tags: discussion, comments

Is there a reason temporal constraint in editing comment is more important than thoughtfulness, on this site? Better for my plodding mind to be precise than fast, isn't it?

Comment: You can just delete the inital comment and post the edited version as a new comment.

Comment: Sah, I use southern as excuse for being slow, dull, not quick on the uptake, couldn't just be me. New to site. It has been given for me to understand that to avoid confusion a timely edit of a mispelled word is better edited but for lengthy addendum better to add comment or do as CaZaNOx above states.

Comment: @CaZaNOx. Thanks - useful information but the time-limit is still a puzzle. Why should it be there even if we can get round it ?

Comment: I moved this question to our Meta site, which is for discussing the main site.

Comment: Just for a bit out-of-SE context, this is done in most major forums and social networks sites generally, with a big example being Twitter which won't let you edit *at all*.

Answer (score 5):

This question is answered on Meta Meta, which is where features common to all SE are discussed. There is nothing special about 5 minutes in particular, but "*if you're allowed to edit a comment for much longer than 5 minutes, it becomes possible to perform an edit on the comment that makes it out of context (no longer makes sense) with the rest of the comments*", and revision history on comments is not recorded, see [Why is the time limit for editing comments only 5 minutes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78573/why-is-the-time-limit-for-editing-comments-only-5-minutes)

Answer (score 3):

If the comment requires a lot of thoughts then it's better to draft it elsewhere before posting (Notepad perhaps). If it's not, then the trivial fix can be added by deleting the old comment and posting a new one.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a reason for the time-restriction on editing comments, I don't know what it is. If I take 3 minutes or 30 minutes over a comment, how am I inconveniencing others ? There is no danger of more time meaning excessively long comments, because comments have a strict word limit.

Comment: On my game system I am confronted with the constraint of bandwidth and as I was denied the ability to edit a comment I prematurely submitted because it took too long, according to my understanding of the error message, I wondered. Thanks.

Comment: Its worse, site also deems all humans incapable of producing more than one submission in less than 40 minutes.

Comment: @Geoffrey Thomas : I think that the inconvenience would be others needing to check for updates to (or changes to) a comment before posting a response that one has written.  If I'm not mistaken, you can spend 30 minutes over a comment, provided that you don't click on "Add Comment."  Once you indicate that you are finished, then the clock starts ticking on the short time available for editing.  So one way to work within the existing restrictions would be to get into a habit of checking your draft comment more thoroughly before clicking on "Add Comment."

Answer (score 2):

This question isn't really about philosophy, it's about the way this website is managed.  However, I agree that a 5-minute editing time is too short.  I just got cut off halfway through improving the clarity of a comment, so the comment survives in a longwinded, less clear form.
I guess the lesson is to write your comment offline.